# Find vertical/horizontal lines

Tags: image-processing, python, computer-vision, opencv

I tried everything including the Hough Transform with different inputs; Laplacian and Sobel and Canny edge detector were run on filtered image but cv2.HoughLinesP and cv2.HoughLines both give me wrong answers. For example, I am able to get the following image:
[image]

However, I can't get the line from this image though HoughLines from cv2. I even tried dilating the image which would make the lines more bolder but nothing.

Source image is:

[image]

Comment: do you have a chance to correct the lens distortion prior to line detection? would make your lines become straight lines

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't; You are right, the lens is distorted so that's making problem. I tried some more complicated hand-made filters and it seemed to work for now.

Comment: Do you have a better sample of the image (The file itself)?